# Error when accessing Count property of an IList in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I try to display the count property of an IList in my ViewModel on the View i get the following error:

> The property System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[WebUI.ViewModels.ItemViewModel, WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].Count could not be found.

The line in my view that riases the error is:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCollection.Count)</td>
```

Upon inspection, the collection is populated correctly and this line of code works correctly:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCollection[0].Id)</td>
```

I clearly have a reference to System.Collections.Generic so I suspect the error is refering to the WebUI.ViewModels.ItemViewModel object. This is accessible when debugging and the error is only raised when accessing Count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you try:

```
<td>@Model.ItemCollection.Count</td>
```

Without the HtmlHelper...

Comment: the line <td>@item.ItemCollection.Count</td> does indeed work, can you think of a reason for this? I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Anthony The HtmlHelper **DisplayFor** expects a Lambda expression that identifies the model object and the property to display, not a property of the Collection class...

Comment: the HTML Helper DisplayFor gives you the ability to overwrite the target. So you could have a view explicitly for your model and have a nice DRY (dont repeat yourself) implementation whenever you wanted to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Cast **IList** to **List** then use List.Count

Try this:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((List<WebUI.ViewModels.ItemViewModel>)item.ItemCollection).Count)</td>
```